# Password hashing security

Tags: php, security

I have a few questions concerning password hashing. I found hash_hmac a pretty good function to hash passwords but a few questions remain.

From another stackoverflow questions someone responded with:

```
return hash_hmac('sha512', $salt . $user['password'], $this->site_key);
```

My initial question concerns how hmac uses the key, on wikipedia it seems that the hmac function would prepend the key to every piece of message before hashing it, does the key itself not act as a salt then? Can I then drop the $salt and just use a user specific key instead? `hash_hmac('sha512', $user['password'], $this->user_key)`

The big question remains the generating of the $salt (or the $user_key from first question). I don't like to store the used salt in the database if I would generate them using rand(). What would then be a good way to generate a user specific salt?

**Update**

If I *would* store the salt in the database, is it safe to use:

```
$user_key = $user['salt'] . $this->site_key;
return hash_hmac('sha512', $user['password'], $user_key);
```

Comment: Why would you use `hash_hmac()` and not `md5()` to hash the passwords?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: How many salted passwords and encrypted with `md5()` have been cracked just because it's fast to generate them? I would like to see an article.

Comment: Many low complexity passwords. Check the recent MtGox dbleak for an example. They used a combination of unsalted(old) and salted(new) password hashes. But even some of the salted passwords were cracked because simple passwords can be bruteforced. An attacker with access to a lot of calculation power(say a botnet) can compute billions of md5 hashes per second.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, simple passwords can be bruteforced, but a salted password is not even close to simple.

Comment: Once the server holding the password hashes has been compromised the salts get compromised too. And that's one of the important attack scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Use a random per user salt and store it together with the hash in the database. Combine it was a per-site secret that's in your config-file. That way an attacker needs to gain access to both the database and the config-file before he can start to crack passwords.

To hash passwords securely I recommend combining three ingredients:

1. A good [Key-Derivation-Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). It's similar to a plain hash, but it's slow and takes a salt. bcrypt and PBKDF2 are common choices.
2. A random per user salt. The main purpose of this is that it's different for each user. You store it together with the hash in the database. No problem if the attacker gets it.
3. A per-site secret. The purpose of this is that getting access to the database is not enough to crack passwords. The attacker needs access to the config file too. And even if he learns the per-site secret the scheme is still as secure as if you had used no secret at all.

Comment: Salts are assumed to be known by the attacker by definition. That's why I use a per-site secret in addition to unique per-user salts. But the security of the scheme must not rely on any secret staying secret, since the whole server might get compromised.

Comment: @Shef The purpose of a salt is to prevent the use of rainbow tables in reversing the password hash. It's not the "key" to the hash or anything like that, a hash has no "key". It takes a long time to find a collision for a salted hash, and that's the main purpose. *You* need to know the salt, so if your server is compromised anyway, the attacker can find it as well. No need to go out of your way to hide the salt. Doing so usually poses only a minor speed bump to an attacker.

Comment: @Shef, deceze and CodeInChaos are right; your comments are incorrect.  The salt (which should be per-user) is not a key to the hash.  Even *knowing* the hash and key, it is still computationally intensive to recover the password.  The purpose is to make the attacker (who in the scenario envisioned already has all data in the database) attack each hash separately.  Normal [rainbow attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) (sharing work between users) can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

**Use bcrypt!**

The classic text on safely storing passwords:

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Quote from the article:

> **Salts Will Not Help You**

*Bonus!*

using bcrypt is simpler than finagling your own bs and likely incorrect salting scheme.

**DON'T EVER IMPLEMENT YOUR OWN CRYPTOSYSTEM OR SOURCE OF ENTROPY**

Comment: Of course salts help, but salts alone are not enough. Using a unique per-user salt prevents the attacker from attacking all hashes in the db at the same time. So if your database has n entries using salts slows the attacker down by a factor of n compared to a db that has no per user salts. That's why any good hashing scheme uses both a slow operation mode and a salt.